# Flutter Flame Game not launching on iOS and macOS

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

I created a simple flame game with no content and was not able to get it running.

**On iOS I get this error:**

`Error (Xcode): ../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flame-1.6.0/lib/src/game/game.dart:25:3: Error: Type 'Images' not found. game.dart:25 Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 14.`

**And on macOS it looks very similar:**

```
: Error: 'Images' isn't a type.
parallax.dart:354
    Images? images,
    ^^^^^^
: Error: 'Images' isn't a type.
parallax.dart:369
    Images? images,
    ^^^^^^
: Error: 'Images' isn't a type.
parallax.dart:393
    Images? images,
    ^^^^^^
: Error: 'Images' isn't a type.
parallax.dart:485
    Images? images,
    ^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Flutter Assemble' from project 'Runner')
** BUILD FAILED **
```

Note, that the error **"Images is not available"** is shown more often then in this code block.

This is how my pubspec.yaml looks like:

```
name: dash_jump
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.4 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flame: ^1.6.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

And this is the code I tried to execute:

```
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(GameWidget(game: MyGame()));
}

class MyGame extends FlameGame {}
```

When I run `flutter doctor -v`, I get this result:

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.7, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64, locale
    de-DE)
    • Flutter version 3.7.7 on channel stable at
      /Users/Max/Documents/Development/SDKs/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2ad6cd72c0 (5 days ago), 2023-03-08 09:41:59 -0800
    • Engine revision 1837b5be5f
    • Dart version 2.19.4
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Volumes/Max/SDK/Android
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at:
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/19.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/
      java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 19.0.2)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at
    /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Volumes/Max/Programme/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.60.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos • darwin-arm64 • macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I am currently using Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.7, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64)

I already tried to clear the cache by running `flutter clean`, I deleted the project and created a new one and ultimately, I also restarted my computer.

Comment: What does your pubspec file look like?

Comment: I added this file a minute ago.

Comment: Looks fine, does `flutter pub get` report any issues?

Comment: No, it doesn't: `Running "flutter pub get" in dash_jump...
Resolving dependencies... 
  async 2.10.0 (2.11.0 available)
  characters 1.2.1 (1.3.0 available)
  collection 1.17.0 (1.17.1 available)
  js 0.6.5 (0.6.7 available)
  matcher 0.12.13 (0.12.14 available)
  meta 1.8.0 (1.9.0 available)
  path 1.8.2 (1.8.3 available)
  test_api 0.4.16 (0.4.18 available)
Got dependencies!`

Comment: Can you add the output of `flutter doctor -v` too?

Comment: Yes, I added my output.

Comment: Looks fine, how are you running the app?

Comment: I normally run it by pressing play in vs code but I also tried to do it by typing `flutter run` in the terminal. Both didn’t work and I get the same error every time.

Comment: I installed Chrome and ran my game in the web and noticed that I get this error also on this platform.

Comment: And you have run flutter create before? Can you run the normal flutter example application that flutter create produces in an empty directory?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I can create "normal" flutter applications without any problems, but I am not able to run that simple game.

Comment: That is very strange, can you join our Discord and I can help you? The comment section here isn't very good for troubleshooting. https://discord.gg/pxrBmy4